# image_dataset_from_directory much faster than flow_from_dataframe. How to speed it up?

Tags: python, image, dataframe, tensorflow, keras

I have an existing evaluation suite that was built for the scikit-learn API. I work with datasets that fit into memory and don't require flowing the data from disk. However, I observe that when I load data with my low level loading function `load_images` I get worse model performance than when I load with either `image_dataset_from_directory` or `flow_from_dataframe`. I could refactor my existing code base to work based on pandas dataframes and use `flow_from_dataframe`, since I need to make these loaders work with scikit-learn KFold splits. There seems to be no straight forward way to do that with `image_dataset_from_directory`, but with `flow_from_dataframe` the index selection makes that possible. The problem now it, that `flow_from_dataframe` is INCREDIBLY slow. I trained 30 models, and it took over 3 hours with `flow_from_dataframe` while with `flow_from_dataframe` it took 8 minutes!

So, I now have 2 options:

- Speed up `flow_from_dataframe`
- Find out what magic preprocessing `flow_from_dataframe` and `image_dataset_from_directory` do that makes the model fit the data better than when loading the data with `load_images`.

I spend a day now on these two options, but failed to do either.

**TL;DR**:

a) Do you know what the critical difference in my low level way of loading the data is compared to the other two high level methods?

b) Do you know how to speed up `flow_from_dataframe`?

**Measurements and code:**

Here are prediction quality measurements I made:

with `flow_from_dataframe`:

[image]

with `image_dataset_from_directory`:

[image]

with `load_images`:

[image]

I did pairwise t-tests. `flow_from_dataframe` and `image_dataset_from_directory` are not significantly different from each other on alpha = .05 and load_images is significantly different (plain to see, actually).

Here are the load functions I used for the evaluation:

```
def load_images(self, image_paths):

    def load_image(path):
        img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(path, target_size=input_shape)
        img = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
        img = img.reshape(1, *input_shape, 3)
        return img

    input_shape = self.model.input.shape[1], self.model.input.shape[2]

    images = np.vstack(list(map(load_image, image_paths)))

    return image        
   

def load_train_data_with_image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir, batch_size, img_height, img_width):
    
    def make_split_ds(split):
        
        ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir, validation_split=0.2, subset=split,
                                                                 image_size=(img_height, img_width), seed=0,
                                                                 batch_size=batch_size, interpolation="nearest",
                                                                 label_mode="categorical")
        return ds
    
    train_ds = make_split_ds("training")
    val_ds = make_split_ds("validation")
    class_names = train_ds.class_names
        
    return train_ds, val_ds, class_names


def load_train_data_with_flow_from_dataframe(data_dir, batch_size, img_height, img_width):
    
    def flow_split(df):
        
        splitgen = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df, directory=TRAIN_DATA_DIR, shuffle=True,
                                               batch_size=batch_size, target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                               interpolation="nearest")
        return splitgen

    data, classes = load_data(["train"])

    X_train, y_train = data["train"]["paths"], data["train"]["labels"]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({"filename": X_train, "class": y_train}).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    
    train_ds = flow_split(df.iloc[: int(len(df) * .8)])
    val_ds = flow_split(df.iloc[int(len(df) * .8): ])
    
    return train_ds, val_ds, classes
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to wrap `image_dataset_from_directory` in a way that allows to use in a more flexible way by unrolling the built-in iterator to get a normal X and y arrays.

```
def load_data(*splits, label_mode="int", **kwargs):

    def load_data_from_directory(data_dir):
        return tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir, label_mode=label_mode, **kwargs)

    def memoize(dataset):
        nonlocal classes

        if not classes:
            classes = dataset.class_names
        elif classes and dataset.class_names != classes:
            raise logger.warning("Splits differ in represented classes.")

        dataset = dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

        return dataset

    def unroll(dataset):

        X, y = map(np.concatenate, zip(*[b for b in dataset.as_numpy_iterator()]))
        return X, y

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    classes = None

    data_dirs = ([TRAIN_DATA_DIR] * ("train" in splits)) + ([TEST_DATA_DIR] * ("test" in splits))

    split_ds = map(memoize, map(load_data_from_directory, data_dirs))
    X, y = map(np.array, map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, zip(*map(unroll, split_ds)))))

    return X, y, classes
```